# The ajax request to an api action in mvc doesn't execute the success event (asp.net webapi)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

[Here is the response from the api action .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G7pk.jpg) I write a web api action as below it works completely done when i call that via ajax request but it wont give the result of success in ajax .
it will pass the action completely without any error but the ajax request just give me an exception and it doesnt successed.

```
$( "#btnSubmit" ).click( function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $( "#sendArticle" );
            if ( !form.valid() ) {
                return false;
            }
            var articles = {

                    "ArticleTitle": $( "#ArticleTitle" ).val(),
                    "CategoryId": $( "#CategoryId" ).val(),
                    "ArticleText": CKEDITOR.instances.ArticleText.getData(),
                    "ArticleImage": "/images/" + $( "div[class='file-caption-name']" ).attr( "title" )

            };


            $.ajax( {
                url:"/api/ArticlesApi/?tags="+ $( "#articleTags" ).val(),                   
                type:"post",
                contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data:JSON.stringify( articles ),
                success: function (data) {

                            $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                            $("#ArticleTitle" ).val( "" );
                            $( "#CategoryId" ).val( "" );
                            CKEDITOR.instances.ArticleText.setData( "" );
                            $.notify( "عملیات با موفقیت انجام شد", "success" );
                },
                error: function () {
                    $.notify( "خطایی رخ داده است", "error" );
                }
            } );
        } );
```

and here is the webapi action

```
public IHttpActionResult PostArticle(Article article, string tags)
    {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }



            article.UserId = "f9afb0fb-3479-4a4e-9460-ecbc642fe089";
            article.ArticleDate = DateTime.Now;
            article.ArticlePoint = 0;
            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (tags != null)
            {
                int[] arrayTag = tags.Split(',').Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToArray();
                foreach (var item in arrayTag)
                {

                    Tag t = new Tag();
                t = db.Tags.Where(c => c.TagId == item).FirstOrDefault();

                article.Tags.Add(t);

                }
                db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = article.ArticleId }, article);
```

Comment: Do you get debug point at web api method ?

Comment: what exact error do you get?

Comment: can you see in the browser console / network tab what the error being returned is? Also if you implement the error callback correctly as per http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and use the variables provided you should get more detail available in your JS which you can use to debug.

Comment: it will pass the webapi action completely without any error, but i dont know why it go to the error event of the ajax request .

Comment: here is the console code : http://localhost:51008/api/ArticlesApi/?tags=1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 2):

you're submitting the wrong data. the API method exepcts "article" and "tags" but you're only submitting "article", and you're not telling it whether that data item is in fact meant to represent "article" or whether it's "tags".

You're submitting tags on the querystring (`url:"/api/ArticlesApi/?tags="+ $( "#articleTags" ).val(),`) even though it's a POST method. the API method will almost certainly ignore this.

Move your tags data into the "data" object of the $.ajax call and you should have more luck.

Comment: it'll go to the api method correctly without any error by passing the values to the api action the problem is that the ajax cannot give the response in the correct way from the api action .

Comment: you're getting a 500 error which suggests there's something going wrong server side. Have you set a debug breakpoint in the API (using visual studio) and verified that the value of the "tags" variable in the server-side is actually what you expect?

Comment: yes my method work nice , without any errors i set up a break point in the api action it pass all the method without any errors .

Comment: 500 definitely means there is some sort of error server-side. Maybe it's not in your action method, maybe it's somewhere else in the pipeline. Have you got any kind of server-side error logging or handling happening that would reveal it?

Comment: i didn't use any server-side error handling, added the debug picture of my api and its response here is the link : http://i.stack.imgur.com/1G7pk.jpg

Comment: yes I saw that. So if it's getting past there, but still returning 500 then something must be wrong elsewhere in the pipeline. Anything in your windows event logs? If not then you need to implement global error handling for your app and start logging.

Answer (score 1):

i find out what my problem :) !!!
i used JavaScriptSerializer to test my api response to be sure that is in the correct Json format .
it provide me an exception and i found what is exactly my problem .
1. i used include in my api action, that is better not to use .
2. i sent something null .
here is the correct code :

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Article))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostArticle(Article article, string tags)
    {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }




            article.UserId = "f9afb0fb-3479-4a4e-9460-ecbc642fe089";
            article.ArticleDate = DateTime.Now;
            article.ArticlePoint = 0;
            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();
            if (tags != null)
            {
                int[] arrayTag = tags.Split(',').Select(id => Convert.ToInt32(id)).ToArray();
                foreach (var item in arrayTag)
                {

                    Tag t = new Tag();
                t = db.Tags.Where(c => c.TagId == item).FirstOrDefault();

                article.Tags.Add(t);

                }
                db.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        var category = db.ArticleCategories;
        var obj = new {article.ArticleDate,article.ArticleId,article.ArticleTitle,article.Category}; 
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(obj);

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = article.ArticleId }, obj);



    }
```